# MySQL: ignore errors when importing?

Tags: mysql, database, import

I am importing a fairly large database. The `.sql` file has almost 1,000,000 lines in it. Problem is that I am getting a syntax error when trying to import the database. It says:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 8428420: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>   **Fatal error**:  Maximum execution time of 600 seconds exceeded in

Normally I'd just open the .sql file and fix the error. But my computer is really struggling to open this file.

Is there any way I can ignore errors when importing a MySQL database?

Comment: Use an editor that does not open the entire file into memory (this is the problem your having to try to edit it) and uses Seek based display for editing on Windows I can Recommend Notepad++ for this task

Answer (score 386):

Use the `--force` (`-f`) flag on your mysql import.  Rather than stopping on the offending statement, MySQL will continue and just log the errors to the console.

For example:

```
mysql -u userName -p -f -D dbName < script.sql
```

Comment: if anyone else wondered about the `-D` in `-D dbName`, it's the same as specifying `--database=dbName `

Comment: I've tested both `-D dbName` and `--database=dbName` and it worked @Aamnah

Comment: I have a question about the -f flag. If there is a syntax error in the timestamp of an insert statement, will it ignore that insert statement alone or that entire block of insert and move on? Kindly advise.