# mysql cmdline client to return error to shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

Is there a way to get the `mysql` cmdline client to abort as soon as it encounters an error, and to return a non-zero exit status to the controlling shell script.

Basically I want to be able to have a shell script like:

```
mysql -A --batch <<END_SQL
UPDATE table1...
UPDATE table2...
...
END_SQL
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    # Error handling
fi
```

With oracle I just had to put `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE` at the top of the sql commands. Is there a mysql equivalent? Not found anything in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the mysql client already does exit when it encounters an error.

You can make the mysql client *not* exit when it encounters an error if you use the `--force` option.

```
$ echo "select * from nonexistanttable ; select now()" | mysql test
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'test.nonexistanttable' doesn't exist

$ echo $?
1
```

Notice this does not return the result of `now()`. It exited first.

```
$ echo "select * from nonexistanttable ; select now()" | mysql --force test
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'test.nonexistanttable' doesn't exist
now()
2017-11-12 22:46:30

$ echo $?
0
```

Ah, there it is.

---

This question is sort of the opposite of [MySQL: ignore errors when importing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263018/mysql-ignore-errors-when-importing)

It's not widely known that this is the behavior of the mysql client. The only clue would have been to read about the `--force` option in this manual page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html