# Best practice for importing a .sql file with error on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a .sql file to MySQL using this command line

`mysql -u username -p  databasename  < path/myfile.sql`

Here is a sample of myfile.sql

```
INSERT INTO mytable (‘id’,’isDeleted’,’amount’,’date’,’description’,’description_clean’,’isDebit’,’account_id’,’user_uuid’) VALUES (3798,'0',35,'0000-00-00','test','test','1',108,'021752f8-7194-4a4b-8919-fb8216ecba07');
INSERT INTO mytable (‘id’,’isDeleted’,’amount’,’date’,’description’,’description_clean’,’isDebit’,’account_id’,’user_uuid’) VALUES (3799,'0',9.4,'2018-05-02','CB Frichti','CB Frichti','1',108,'316a3da6-821b-42c8-80ea-3c1ac437484e');
INSERT INTO mytable (‘id’,’isDeleted’,’amount’,’date’,’description’,’description_clean’,’isDebit’,’account_id’,’user_uuid’) VALUES (3800,'0',50,'0000-00-00','test','test','1',108,'316a3da6-821b-42c8-80ea-3c1ac437484e');
```

My file contains some date but some of those are wrong date `0000-00-00`. Therefore the command above returns an error.

What is the best way to import ? Should I remove the line where date is wrong ? Is there a way to import only import lines that are correct and ignore those with error ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Replace '0000-00-00'  in a text editor with NULL (if the column is nullable) or a default date '1900-01-01' then you can either use the data as is or delete it one you have imported. (`INSERT INTO ‘‘` doesn't look correct either)

Comment: @AlexK sounds like you should put that as an answer :)

Comment: Insert into...nothing?

Comment: If you want to clean up your data first, keep in mind it's often a lot easier to edit as CSV and then [import that with `LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table). Most any spreadsheet tool can read and write CSV, making edits pretty effortless and bulk search/replace isn't even that hard.

Comment: Or load it into a temporary table where the columns are just character, and then write some SQL with case statements etc. to clean it up and populate the production table - that way you (effectively) have a record of what you changed, and you can potentially re-use it next time you get a batch of nasty data to load.

Comment: @tadman the thing is I don't have the data in CSV format it is only in this format so far

Comment: You can always import it, dump it as CSV, fix it up, and reload it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263018/mysql-ignore-errors-when-importing)

You can use the `--force (-f)` flag on your `mysql` import. Rather than stopping, MySQL will continue and just log the errors to the console.

For example:

```
mysql -u username -p -f -D path/myfile.sql < path/myfile.sql
```

Replacing invalid values with a default value (e.g., `1900-01-01`) is not a good practice, you should prefer `NULL` instead